# Generate package config file automagically using Scons, bjam, and/or cmake

Tags: scons, bjam, dpkg, pkg-config

Hey Stackoverflowers: one comment and one question.

Comment: You guys/girls are great, thanks for taking a look.

Question:

Can Bjam, Scons, or Cmake easily install a .pc file for library projects?

I find it really annoying that I have to maintain the same library dependency list in my scons/bjam/make file, the .pc file (for libraries), and rpm/deb package config files.

It would be nice if a build tool could manage the build and installation meta-data.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Because SCons is such a flexible environment, yes you can in fact use it to manage the entire process from building to deliverable package.

Our build goes through several phases with SCons:

1. Build - resulting .o, .os, generated files, etc under ./build
2. Assembly - resulting exe, so/dll, binarys, etc under ./delivery
3. Packing & configuration - a set of deb/rpm/msi + configuration, etc under ./package

It isn't all out of the box, and requires you to write some python code, find tools etc, but it does work for us pretty well.

Our project is C, C++, Java, & Python building dozens of binary targets for a distributed system with multiple delivery targets for different machine installs on Windows, Ubuntu and Redhat Linux.

Again, be prepared to have to customize your scripts and write custom builders though to wrap different processes.